# SPF softfail dragging me to an abyss

Tags: dns, php, spf

Mail sent from my PHP is not delivered to some clients and this I am suspecting could be due to SPF test returning a `softfail` with `domain of transitioning` . The message details are below:

```
Delivered-To: eric.clapton@gmail.com
Received: by 10.50.73.42 with SMTP id i10csp74854igv;
    Mon, 7 Oct 2013 03:21:52 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.68.44.33 with SMTP id b1mr2455965pbm.53.1381141311313;
    Mon, 07 Oct 2013 03:21:51 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <craig@abc.com>
Received: from mtarelay2.ops.gq1.yahoo.net (mtarelay2.ops.gq1.yahoo.net. [98.136.240.39])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTP id f6si4349525pba.278.1969.12.31.16.00.00;
    Mon, 07 Oct 2013 03:21:51 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning craig@abc.com does not     designate 98.136.240.39 as permitted sender) client-ip=98.136.240.39;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning craig@abc.com does not designate 98.136.240.39 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=craig@abc.com
Received: from p10db3.geo.gq1.yahoo.com (p10db3.geo.gq1.yahoo.com [67.195.61.18])
by mtarelay2.ops.gq1.yahoo.net (Postfix) with ESMTP id 764E0511EB
for <eric.clapton@gmail.com>; Mon,  7 Oct 2013 10:21:35 +0000 (UTC)
Received: (from root@localhost)
by p10db3.geo.gq1.yahoo.com (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id r97ALZiJ005899;
Mon, 7 Oct 2013 03:21:35 -0700
Date: Mon, 7 Oct 2013 03:21:35 -0700
Message-Id: <201310071021.r97ALZiJ005899@p10db3.geo.gq1.yahoo.com>
To: eric.clapton@gmail.com
Subject: Client invoice
From: craig@abc.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

SPF settings for my domain is:

```
v=spf1 a mx ~all
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check what IPs are allowed to send emails from the sender domain. This website lets you see all allowed IPs:
http://spf.myisp.ch

If the sender IP does not match any IP or IP range it shows you then you might need to edit the SPF settings.

Comment: I checked on that link and this is what it says: `allow if the IP matches an A or AAAA record of abc.com
67.195.61.65
allow if the IP matches an MX record of abc.com
mx-biz.mail.am0.yahoodns.net.
98.139.171.245
soft deny all IPs which do not match any previous rule`

Comment: Would adding `mtarelay2.ops.gq1.yahoo.net` to the MX record of my domain fix this problem? `mtarelay2.ops.gq1.yahoo.net` seems to be the sender from the transcript details

Comment: What I understand is that you use the web hosting services of Yahoo and you want to be able to send emails from the yahoo web server and from your email client. Am I correct?

Comment: 1. Your SPF entries need to include all IP addresses of the mail servers (of the mail hoster) which send out your emails.

Comment: 2. Your SPF entries neet to include all IPs from which your web server sends emails.

Comment: I guess your mail hoster uses a range of IPs. So you could specify a range in the SPF entry (e.g. 127.0.0.0/31).

I think the emails that you send using your web site might come from several different IPs. So you might have to use a range for the yahoo IPs as well. (e.g. 10.0.0.0/24)

So your SPF entry would look like this:

`example.com.   3600   IN   TXT   "v=spf1 ip4:127.0.0.0/31 ip4:10.0.0.0/24 ~all"`

Comment: I have added `mtarelay2.ops.gq1.yahoo.net` and `mtarelay1.ops.gq1.yahoo.net` to MX records and SPF test now registers a `pass`. What is wrong about doing it this way rather than specify IPs in SPF as you mentioned?

Comment: Those two servers are not your MX servers. MX servers are for receiving E-Mail. It is technically wrong to add additional IPs which cannot accept emails. It seams like you should inform yourself a bit better about how SPF works exactly. The use of SPF is controversial as it can cause problems receiving legitimate emails. I suggest you to read this Wikipedia page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework#FAIL_and_forwarding

Comment: Oh thanks! The two IP addresses I have seen so far sending mails from my hosting are `98.136.240.39` and `98.136.240.37`. So if i set SPF to `v=spf1 ip4:98.136.240.0/24 ~all`, this should just do fine? right?.

Comment: Probably. Yahoo has a ton of IP addresses. I would ask Yahoo what IP ranges you should use for your SPF entry. Don't forget the IPs of your mail provider! You have to add those as well.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that stands out are `Received: (from root@localhost)`, which is bound to give an error. Many spam blockers, including googles, doesn't allow localhost to be inside the HELO string. I just had the same error on a Ubuntu Server using Postfix, and the solution was to edit `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to have:

```
myhostname = abc.com
```

and then restart the postfix service.

```
sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf
sudo /etc/init.d/postfix restart
```